# Tsql implicitly trying to convert a zip-code string to an int when inserting

Tags: sql, t-sql, type-conversion, varchar, implicit

I'm sure this has been asked and answered but I couldn't find it. I'm new to TSQL. I'm trying to 'Insert Into' several zip code records (strings) into a table that was built before my time. The column is set to varchar(255). Not sure what the other 245 characters are for...

When I try to insert the values, SqlServer tries to implicitly convert the text strings to ints and fails.

```
INSERT INTO db.table (city,zip)
    SELECT 'New York','12345-1234' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Pittsburgh','98765-4321';
```

It returns "Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '12345-1234' to data type int."

Any help would be appreciated.

OK...Back in the office. This is a screengrab of the zip column i'm trying to insert into.  It is a varchar and the above code is correctly representative of what I'm trying to do.  Is it the 'UNION ALL'?

[Zip column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfX44.png)

Comment: In my experience SQL Server only attempts to convert between data types when the columns require it. The query you have listed is syntactically incorrect and will not run. Can you provide the actual query you are attempting to run?

Comment: could be asked in dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Perhaps the table is designed to store a Zone Improvement Plan code consisting of five digits as an integer. The ZIP+4 codes have only been around since 1983, so they might not be accommodated yet.

Answer (score 0):

This value is not an integer, the field where you are inserting it must be a string of lesser precision, must be the longest you can receive.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.  I figured it out.  In the large data-set I was inserting, there was some sloppily entered data that was being picked up as an int. TSQL then tries to convert to the data-type that's higher up on the hierarchy and breaks the insert.

Thanks for the help all.